# Why are all of the list items in my nested list navigation displayed directly on top of each other?

Tags: css, positioning

Nested list navigation is not displaying the second list as I'd expect (block listed down vertically).  Instead all items are placed directly on top of one another.

http://jsfiddle.net/HL69H/3/

```
<div id="linksLeft">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="">about</a></li>
            <li class="current" id="active"><a href="">portfolio</a>
                <ul class="subMenu" id="subNav">
                    <li><a href="">editorial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">advertising</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">packaging</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">photography</a></li>    
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


#nav {
width:48em;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
padding-top:6em;
list-style-type:none;
}

#outerBox {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#linksLeft{
float:left;
border-top:2px solid #93b9bb;
border-bottom:2px solid #93b9bb;
margin-top:60px;
padding:5px 0px;
}

#linksLeft li {
display:inline-block;
padding:0 3em;
position:relative;
}
#linksLeft li ul li {
display:block;
}

#subNav li{
position:absolute;
padding:1em;
left:50%;
/*display:none;*/
}

#linksRight li{
display:inline-block;
padding:0 3em;
position:relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `position:absolute` for `#subNav li` piles them on top of each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `position: absolute;` was stacking them. Changing this to relative, and use absolute positioning on the parent container to position it where you want it.

```
#subNav li{
    position:relative;
    padding:1em;
    left:50%;
    /*display:none;*/
}
```

Comment: How do I get that ul outside of normal flow so it doesn't bump the border down?  I thought that's what the absolute positioning did?

Comment: You're right, just set `position: absolute` on #subNav. http://jsfiddle.net/HL69H/9/

Comment: the position: relative on the subnav li is absolutely not needed and has no effect. As I said in my answer, the problem is, that the parent ul must be positioned and not the li's

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your css for '#subnav li'. The style you apply you want for the ul but not the li.

CSS

```
#subNav {
    position:absolute;
    padding:1em;
    left:0;
    /*display:none;*/
}

#menu li{
    position:relative;
}
```

That gives you what you want